# Complex filtering

Tags: c#, infragistics

I want to create a complex filtering such that

(ColumnA==X Or ColumnA==Y ) AND (ColumnB==Z Or ColumnC==W)

What I did is:

```
ultraGridResults.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].ColumnFilters.LogicalOperator = FilterLogicalOperator.And;
ultraGridResults.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].ColumnFilters["ColumnA"].FilterConditions.Add(FilterComparisionOperator.Equals, X);
ultraGridResults.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].ColumnFilters["ColumnA"].FilterConditions.Add(FilterComparisionOperator.Equals, Y);
ultraGridResults.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].ColumnFilters["ColumnA"].LogicalOperator = FilterLogicalOperator.Or;
ultraGridResults.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].ColumnFilters["ColumnB"].FilterConditions.Add(FilterComparisionOperator.Equals, Z);
ultraGridResults.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].ColumnFilters[ColumnC].FilterConditions.Add(FilterComparisionOperator.Equals, W);
```

The problem is that since ColumnB is different then ColumnC I dont know how to insert the "Or" between this two conditions.
And the result I get is:

(ColumnA == X Or ColumnA == Y) AND (ColumnB ==Z) AND (ColumnB ==W)
Instead of what I wanted which is:

(ColumnA==X Or ColumnA==Y ) AND (ColumnB==Z Or ColumnC==W)

How can I write the filter so it will have an Or operator in the right side also?
Thanks

Comment: It is just a typo or do you have really two different grids?

Comment: Not sure that this is possible. I am not able to reach your intended result. I think that you should ask on their support site (or refer to this question). Like to know myself.

Comment: Probably the best approach here is to filter the datasource instead of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is what you would want.** Consider that all the Columns are the same datatype, if not you can always convert or parse the values:

```
if (ColumnA == X || ColumnA == Y && ColumnB==Z || ColumnC == W)
{
//Code here
}
```

Please send me feedback if this help you at all.

Comment: Thanks but this won't work since i need an infragistics filtering